# using org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator vs just putting all bundles into osgi.bundles

Tags: java, eclipse, equinox

I am upgrading our Equinox from 4.7.3a to 4.21 in our server application. I have learned the hard way that `org.eclipse.update.configurator` no longer does automatically install bundles on application startup ([1](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=542706)). It seems my choices are either start using p2 repositories or start using `SimpleConfigurator`. `SimpleConfigurator` seems easier to implement in my case.

One thing I do not understand, **what does `SimpleConfigurator` offer me over just enumerating all bundles in `osgi.bundles` property?** It requires `bundles.info` file anyway which is also a static list of bundles. I will have to generate the bundles list one way or another. Can I do away with any configurator?

Comment: The simple configurator bundles.info gets built automatically from the product file info by the tycho build.

Comment: @greg-449 OK. But we do not use Tycho build. Is there a detectable difference between putting the bundles into `osgi.bundles` property and using the `SimpleConfigurator`'s `bundles.info`?

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer that, I have only ever used the simple configurator method.

Comment: I wasted way too much time thinking the same. Due to the fact that this code has been removed from Equinox, you now have the choice between forking Equinox or following best practice by simply using Tycho to build. Besides an easier build, another benefit of switching to Tycho would be to speed up starting time of your application.